# Geting rx/tx timestamps from TP-Link 722N

Tags: c, linux, timestamp

I am trying to measure distance between two computers who are connected with a wifi ad-hoc by using time of arrival to determine the distance.

I am using TP-Link 722N with Atheros AR9271 chipset and ath9k_htc Driver I am trying to get rx/tx timestamps from the wlan card, is there any way to get rx/tx timestamps to do the necessary calculations to get the distance between the computers?

Comment: Why do you think having those timestamps will correlate in _any_ meaningful way with the distance between the computers? The propagation delay is likely to be 1-2 orders of magnitude smaller than delay introduced by all the stuff between the two computers: WiFi radio, router, collisions, packet loss & retry, interrupt and processing latency on the remote system (for the ping reply), etc.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough on the part of getting hardware timestamps, if you get the hardware timestamps when you send and receive packets e.g. when pinging the other computer you should be able to remove the processing time and be left with only the time it takes the signal to move from one computer to the other computer and back.

Here is an example of the timestamps needed
http://www.ipcsit.com/vol26/4-ICTTE2012-T009.pdf
in figure 4 on page 3 in the pdf and the calculation on the bottom of the page

Comment: The very first thing that paper says is that you can't get the required accuracy from off-the-shelf hardware, and you need a special hardware timing device (the TPU) between the wifi adapter and the computer.  Have you decided to ignore the preconditions?  Again, what makes you think you can ignore them?

Answer (score 0):

Seems unrealistic since minimum packet size * rate >> transit time.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.